# I am making a study about connecting the unfolded square pyramids, can you help or suggest something?

Tags: geometry

I am making a study about connecting the unfolded square pyramids, or simply connecting the vertices of the nets of the square pyramid, and my goal now is to find the area of the unoccupied space when these nets are enclosed in a square (see the figure below). I already made a formula. But can i ask some help or suggestions, to make my study more interesting, to have more twists and make my study more complicated?pls help me.

[image: here there is only one layer of unfolded square pyramid]
[image: here there is two layers of unfolded square pyramid]
[image: here there is three layers of unfolded square pyramid]

The formula I already made is the area of the spaces,color white, in the figure.

Comment: I removed some of your tags as they did not seem at all appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move and/or rotate the enclosing square in a way that there are intersections between the edges of the square and the unfolded pyramids (cutting them into pieces). Or you could use other enclosing shapes, such as rectangles, arbitrary quadrilaterals or circles.